# Image of a projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> Show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for normal bounded linear operator $N$ on Hilbert space $H$ with spectral measure $E$ iff $E(\{\lambda\})\neq 0$, in which case the range of $E(\{\lambda\})$ is the eigenspace $\ker (N-\lambda)$.

My difficulty for this Exercise is showing that $E(\{\lambda\})H = \ker(N-\lambda)$ when $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $N$.I just know that $E(\{\lambda\})H \subset \ker(N-\lambda)$ , but for converse I can not show it. Please give me a hint. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any bounded Borel function $f$, and Borel subset $S\subset\mathbb{C}$,
$$
                      E(S)\int f(s)dE(s)x =\int_{S} f(s)dE(s)x,\;\;\; x \in H.
$$
And $\int s dE(s)x = Ax$. Therefore, $\mathcal{R}(E(\{\lambda\}))\subseteq\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I)$ follows from
$$
       (A-\lambda I)E(\{\lambda\})x=E(\{\lambda\})(A-\lambda I)x=\int_{\{\lambda\}}(s-\lambda)dE(s)x=0.                
$$
Conversely, suppose $(A-\lambda I)x=0$. For any $\rho > 0$, let $E_{\rho}=E(\{ \mu : |\mu-\lambda| \ge \rho > 0\})$. Then, using properties of the spectral integral,
$$
   0= \|E_{\rho}(A-\lambda I)x\|^{2}=\|(A-\lambda I)E_{\rho}x\|^{2} \ge \rho^{2}\|E_{\rho}x\|^{2}.
$$
Hence, $E_{\rho}x=0$ for all $\rho > 0$, which gives $E(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\lambda\})x=0$. Hence, $E(\{\lambda\})x=x$.

Comment: How do you claim $\|(A-\lambda)E_\rho x\|^2 \geq \rho^2\|E_\rho x\|^2$? I think $\|(A-\lambda)E_\rho x\|^2 \leq \rho^2\|E_\rho x\|^2$ satisfies.

Comment: $\|(A-\lambda I)E_{\rho}x\|^{2}=\int_{|s-\lambda|\ge \rho}|s-\lambda|^{2}d\|E(s)x\|^{2} \ge \int_{|s-\lambda| \ge \rho}\rho^{2}d\|E(s)x\|^{2} =\rho^{2}\int_{|s-\lambda|\ge \rho}d\|E(s)x\|^{2}=\rho^{2}\|E_{\rho}x\|^{2}$

Comment: How do you claim $E(\{\lambda\})x=x$?

Comment: @niki : Because $E(\{ s : |s-\lambda| > 0\})x=0$, and $E(\mathbb{C})x=x$, then $E(\{\lambda\})x=x$. Keep in mind that $\lim_{n}E(\{ s : |s-\lambda| \ge 1/n\})x=E(\{ s : |s-\lambda| > 0\})x$ because $E$ is a spectral measure.

Comment: Excellent, It's a nice proof. I really learn new things from this proof.

Comment: @niki : Glad I could help. A good worked out example always helped me more than anything, too.